# Python. Trying to get index[0] == index[1]

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

i get a index out of range error when i run this code. it works if tmp > 3 and if tmp[2] == tmp[3]. im trying to write to file the numbers in index[0] when conditions are met. aka tmp[0] == tmp[1]. Why is I can't call tmp[0], no matter what I've tried.

```
i = 0
tmp = []
while(i < len(sequence)):
    tmp = sequence[i].replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",")
    if(len(tmp) > 1):
        if(tmp[0] == tmp[1]):
            print tmp[0]
            with open(output_file1, 'a') as output:
                output.write(str(tmp[0])  + '\n')
i = i+1
return True

python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 71, in <module>
generate(6, out_path2,out_path1, out_path)
File "app.py", line 45, in generate
random6th = random.choice(sequence2).replace("[", "").replace("]","").replac
e("'","").replace(" ","")
File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 275, in choice
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is emp
ty
IndexError: list index out of range

i = 0
tmp = []
while(i < len(sequence)):
    tmp.append(sequence[i].replace("(","").replace(")","").split(","))
    if(len(tmp) > 0):
        if(tmp[0] == tmp[1]):
            print tmp[0]
            with open(output_file1, 'a') as output:
                output.write(str(tmp[0])  + '\n')
i = i+1
return True

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 69, in <module>
generate_2(seq_path, out_path1, out_path2);
File "app.py", line 20, in generate_2
if(tmp[0] == tmp[1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

With the 2nd code I got another traceback error, at if(tmp[0] == tmp[1]
With PRINT tmp[0], never runs cuz of the above error with 2nd code traceback.

A sequence looks like this

```
(8, 16, 5, 5, 65, 27)
(7, 15, 4, 4, 64, 26)
(21, 17, 12)
(22, 22, 11, 11, 59, 24)
(21, 21, 10, 9, 58, 23)
```

I'm trying to match 21 and 21 tmp[0] == tmp[1] and then write to file 21.

Comment: can you share the exact traceback?

Comment: Can you also give us an output of `print(tmp)` after the assignment?

Comment: `sequence[i].replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",")` that looks like a poor man's `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: What is `index[0]`? (You also do not change `i` anywhere in the loop.)

Comment: index[0] is a number in a list of 6 digits like 1 2 3 4 5 6, where 1 is index[0]

Comment: what does sequence look like? From your code, I'm guessing it is a list or other python sequence where each element is a string something like this: `(Thing1),Thing2,ThingN` and because you're checking if `len(tmp) > 0`, I'm guessing that sometimes sequence has no elements in it? If you give me a sense of what sequence refers to, I can help you solve your problem.

Comment: you're passing an empty list to `choice`: ` # raises IndexError if seq is empty`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `tmp = []` before your `while` loop, but then you re-assign it every time you're in the loop. Your code should instead be:

```
i = 0
tmp = []
while(i < len(sequence)):
    tmp.append(sequence[i].replace("(","").replace(")","").split(","))
    if(len(tmp) > 1):
        if(tmp[0] == tmp[1]):
            print tmp[0]
            with open(output_file1, 'a') as output:
                output.write(str(tmp[0])  + '\n')
```

This might resolve your issues.

Comment: append a list to a list is probably not what the OP wants

Comment: Since `sequence[i]` looks like an item in a list, it would be appending an item of the sequence (which looks to be a string in this context).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like that data is in a list of strings (given that you are calling string methods), so with that assumption, this should work:

```
# sequences = \
# """(8, 16, 5, 5, 65, 27)
# (7, 15, 4, 4, 64, 26)
# (21, 17, 12)
# (22, 22, 11, 11, 59, 24)
# (21, 21, 10, 9, 58, 23)"""
# sequences = sequences.split('\n')

# Alternatively, if the data is within a textfile called sequence.txt
with open(os.path.join(home_dir, 'sequence.txt'), 'r') as infile:
    sequences = infile.read().splitlines(keepends=False)

output_file1 = 'good_sequences.txt'

# assuming you were using mode='a' only because open was called each iteration, otherwise change to 'a'
with open(output_file1, 'w') as outfile:  
    for sequence in sequences:
        seq_data = sequence.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')
        if seq_data and len(seq_data) > 2:
            if seq_data[0] == seq_data[1]:
                print(seq_data[0])
                # didn't see a need to cast as str
                outfile.write(seq_data[0] + '\n')
```

The output will be:

```
22
21
```

Comment: that code works working with it but, sequences = os.path.join(home_dir, 'sequence.txt') im using and it wont print seq_data[0]

Comment: that last one doesn't output anything to file or print seq_data[0], no print no output tho

Comment: Try putting sequence.txt in the same folder as your code and then use `with open('sequence.txt', 'r') as infile` If this works, then the problem you're having is different than the one we're answering here. If it does not work, then I don't understand how your data file is organized. I'm testing this code with this sequence.txt: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0fy10t7mmb8mdt/sequence.txt?dl=0 Is it the same as yours?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way i solved this was change int(tmp[0]) == int(tmp[1]) did the trick works beautifully now.